# JavaFX error - Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I get this error message, when i try calling a method "undo" in the object invoker of class `Invoker`:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at view.MainWindow.lambda$2(MainWindow.java:112)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm guessing the problem has to do with the javafx thread? I have tried using Platform.runLater, but the problem persisted.

I'm launching a JavaFX window through this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board board = new Board();
    Invoker invoker = new Invoker();
    TileBoardController tbc = new TileBoardController();
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(()->{});
    mainWindow.launch(board, tbc.CreateTiles(board), invoker);
    com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.exit();
}
```

And the event that crashes the program lies in a menu bar in that "MainWindow" class:

```
menuOptions.setOnAction(e -> invoker.undo());
```

Strange thing is, the invoker class works, and is successfully used in another part of the same "MainWindow" object:

```
tileBoardStatic[rank][file].setOnAction( e -> this.onTileClick(finalRank, finalFile));

private void onTileClick(int rank, int file) {

        invoker.storeAndExecute(new MovePiece(board, activeTile.getSquare(), tileBoardStatic[rank][file].getSquare()));

}
```

I have tried `invoker.undo()` in that same method, and that works.
Anyone know what the problem is here?

Here is all the code in `MainWindow`:

```
public class MainWindow extends Application{

    public static final int TILE_SIZE = 100;
    public static final int WIDTH = 8;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 8;

    private Invoker invoker;
    private static Group tileGroup = null;
    private static Tile[][] tileBoardStatic = null;
    private Tile activeTile;
    private Board board;


    public void launch(Board board, Tile[][] tileBoard, Invoker invoker) {
        this.board = board;
        this.tileBoardStatic = tileBoard;
        this.invoker = invoker;
        tileGroup = new Group();
        for (int rank=0; rank<tileBoard.length; rank++) {
            for(int file=0; file<tileBoard[rank].length; file++) {
                final int finalRank = rank;
                final int finalFile = file;
                tileBoardStatic[rank][file].setOnAction( e -> this.onTileClick(finalRank, finalFile));
                tileGroup.getChildren().add(tileBoard[rank][file]);
            }
        }
        Application.launch(MainWindow.class);
    }


    //Handles click event for Tiles
    private void onTileClick(int rank, int file) {


        if (activeTile == null) {
            if (tileBoardStatic[rank][file].getSquare().getPiece() == null) 
                System.out.println("No piece in tile");
            else {
                if(tileBoardStatic[rank][file].getSquare().getPiece().isWhite() != board.getTurnIsWhite()) {
                    System.out.println("Not your turn");
                } else {
                    activeTile = tileBoardStatic[rank][file];
                    activeTile.getStyleClass().add("tile-clicked");
                }
            }
        } 
        else {
            activeTile.getStyleClass().removeAll("tile-clicked");
            //Creates and sends command to invoker
            invoker.storeAndExecute(new MovePiece(board, activeTile.getSquare(), tileBoardStatic[rank][file].getSquare()));

            //Repaints squares
            activeTile.paintSquare();
            tileBoardStatic[rank][file].paintSquare();

            activeTile = null;
        }



    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("resources/chess.png")));
        root.getChildren().addAll(tileGroup);
        root.setPrefSize(WIDTH * TILE_SIZE, HEIGHT * TILE_SIZE);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MainWindow");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(MainWindow.class.getResource("resources/stylesheet.css").toExternalForm());



        //Menu bar
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu gameMenu = new Menu("Game");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(gameMenu);
        MenuItem menuExit = new MenuItem("Exit game");
        menuExit.setOnAction(e -> exit());
        gameMenu.getItems().add(menuExit);
        Menu menuOptions = new Menu("Edit");
        MenuItem menuUndo = new MenuItem("Undo");
        menuOptions.setOnAction(e -> invoker.undo());
        menuOptions.getItems().add(menuUndo);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menuOptions);



        root.setTop(menuBar);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    private void exit() {
        Platform.exit();
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You're launching your application incorrectly. Your `main` method initializes some objects, including an instance of `MainWindow`. You then call a method on said instance of `MainWindow` which sets some fields then calls `Application.launch`. This is where the problem manifests: The call to `Application.launch` results in a *new, separate* instance of `MainWindow` to be created. It is *this* instance that is used by the JavaFX runtime.

Since the `start(Stage)` method is invoked on an instance other than the one you called `launch(Board,Tile[][],Invoker)` on, none of the instance fields are set properly; this ultimately leads to your `NullPointerException`. Your solution to make `invoker` static merely covers up a symptom of the larger problem—initializing objects outside the typical life-cycle.

Try changing your `main` method to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(MainWindow.class, args);
}
```

*Note: If the `main` method is inside the `Application` subclss, you can use `launch(args)` instead.*

Then move all the initializing logic to ether `Application#init()` or `Application#start(Stage)` (or at least call the appropriate method(s) from inside one of them). Any initializing that requires the *JavaFX Application Thread* should be done in the `start` method; the `init` method is called on the *JavaFX-Launcher* thread.

Also, using `Application.launch` will implicitly startup the JavaFX runtime. There's no reason for you to manually call `PlatformImpl.startup`. You should also avoid using internal code (e.g. `com.sun.*`) unless there's no other option. If you find yourself needing to use internal code, take a step back and check if you're perhaps doing something wrong.

Comment: Ok, i will try that. Thanks alot for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! All i had to do was to set my invoker object to static, of course. Stupid miss.

```
private static Invoker invoker;
```

Comment: A comment more or less for others who might read this thread:
I would go with the answer below from Slaw, this is the correct way to initialize a JavaFX app.